# i need to route to another page after login in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes

how to route login page to dashboard in vuejs after validating login credential entered by user. i have given login method and component thats to be routed....................................................................................................................................................

```
        <template>
          <div class="login-wrapper border border-light">
           <div  class="form-signin">
              <h2  >Please sign in</h2>

              <input v-model="email" type="text"   class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" required autofocus>

              <input v-model="password" type="password"   class="form-control" placeholder="Password " required>
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" @click="check()">Sign in</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>

        <script>

        import Vue from 'vue';
        import Router from 'vue-router';

        import Dashboard  from '../pages/Dashboard.vue';


        export default {
          name: 'Login',
          data () {
            return {
              email: '',
              password: ''
            }
          },
          methods: {
            check() {

              if( this.email == 'admin' && this.password == 'admin'){
            //need to route
              }
              }
          }
        }; 
        </script>


         route to below component after login validated
      component: DashboardLayout,
      redirect: "/dashboard",

// how to config app.vue to route login page


      <template>
        <div>
         <router-view ></router-view>
        </div>
      </template>

      <script>
        export default {

        };
      </script>


      // below is my route.js

        import DashboardLayout from "@/layout/dashboard/DashboardLayout.vue";
        // GeneralViews
        import NotFound from "@/pages/NotFoundPage.vue";
        import Login from "@/pages/login.vue" 
        // Admin pages
        const Dashboard = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */"@/pages/Dashboard.vue");
        const pole = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "common" */ "@/pages/Poles.vue");

        const routes = [
          {
        path: "/",
            component: Login,

            children: [
              {
                path: "dashboard",
                name: "dashboard",
                component: Dashboard
              },
              {
                path: "Poles",
                name: "Poles",
                component: pole
              } 
            ]
          },
          { path: "*", component: NotFound },
        ];
            export default routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have single `Vue` instance for your routes, you can use `this.$router.push({ name: 'component' })`:

```
methods: {
        check() {
        if( this.email == 'admin' && this.password == 'admin'){
           this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' });
           //OR with relative path
           this.$router.push({ path: '/dashboard' });
          }
         }
         ...
```

Comment: Route with name 'DashboardLayout' does not exist

Comment: Can you show your routes config? You can give `name: 'something'` to your routes as well.

Comment: const routes = [
  {
path: "/",
    component: Login,
    
    children: [
      {
        path: "dashboard",
        name: "dashboard",
        component: Dashboard
      },
      {
        path: "Poles",
        name: "Poles",
        component: pole
      },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197760/discussion-between-ambianbeing-and-pavan).

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can easily to do that with this:

```
check() {
   if( this.email == 'admin' && this.password == 'admin'){
        window.location = "/dashboard"
    }
}
```